# Configuring Spring Security To Work With Two Different Login Pages

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, form-authentication

One of the situations in which we may need two login pages is when we have one page for administrators of an application and a different page for normal users.
Each http element will have a different login page and a different login processing URL

I have got this Spring boot security config for allowing login for multiple page.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class App1ConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        public App1ConfigurationAdapter() {
            super();
        }

        @Autowired
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Value("${admin-users-query}")
        private String usersQuery;

        @Value("${admin-roles-query}")
        private String rolesQuery;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            auth.
                    jdbcAuthentication()
                    .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/admin*")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/admin/temp/login")
                    .failureUrl("//admin/temp?error=loginError")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/admin/temp/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/temp")
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403").and().csrf();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class App2ConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        @Value("${user-users-query}")
        private String usersQuery;

        @Value("${user-roles-query}")
        private String rolesQuery;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            auth.
                    jdbcAuthentication()
                    .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/user*")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user/temp/login")
                    .failureUrl("/user/temp/?error=loginError")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/temp")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/user/temp/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/user/temp/login")
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()enter code here
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403").and().csrf();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class guestSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/js/***", "/js/****");
        }
    }
```

**Admin login form /admin/temp/login**

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/temp/login}" method="post">
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" data-validation="required" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"  data-validation="required" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4" value="Login">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

**User login form /user/temp/login**

```
<form th:action="@{/user/temp/login}" method="post">
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="username" data-validation="required" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password"  data-validation="required" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4" value="Login">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6 text-right">
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

When I Submit the form I get

```
**Code: 405
(Method Not Allowed)**

When I use single form the form get submted.

Does anyone has an idea on whats happening her?
```

Comment: Coulld you try `http.antMatcher("/admin/**")` instead of `http.antMatcher("/admin*")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spring assumes that URL to validate the credentials is `/login`. To change it you should set up `loginProcessingUrl` for both `formLogin` configurations.

It should be something like:

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/user/temp/login")
.failureUrl("/user/temp/?error=loginError")
.defaultSuccessUrl("/user/temp")
.usernameParameter("username")
.passwordParameter("password")
.loginProcessingUrl("/user/temp/login") # missing line
```

Answer (score 2):

As someone already answered you need to add

```
               .loginPage("/login.html")  
               .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/temp/login")
```

The default URL where the Spring Login will POST to trigger the authentication process is /login which used to be /j_spring_security_check before Spring Security 4.